# How to convert a Stream into an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to convert a Stream into an Object.

I have a WebApi

```
[HttpGet]
    public AttachmentViewModel DownloadAttachementDetailsByIds(int attachementDetaisId)
    {
        AttachmentViewModel attachment = new AttachmentViewModel
        {
            AttachmentName = "Observe",
            AttachmentType = ".c",
            AttachmentDetailsID = 123,
            AttachmentDetails = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some contant"),
            AttachmentSize = 12 //some valid size
        };

        return attachment;
    }
```

Now I'm calling this GET method as bellow:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(documentRepositoryApiUrl + "DocRepoApi/DownloadAttachementDetailsById?attachementDetaisId=97");
```

Well, my call is successful but once I get all data into my stream how can I again retrieve them all as the same `AttachmentViewModel` object. And if the API returns any error how to read it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`DownloadString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) method from `WebClient` and deserialize it into your model (by using JSON.NET for example).

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
var data = webClient.DownloadString(url);
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttachmentViewModel>(data);
```

If an error occurs, a corresponding `WebException` will be thrown.