# C# - better way to get data from API?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create currency converter from `ETH` to `CZK` and I am using APIs to get the balance of my account and an actual exchange rate of `CZK`.

I am using this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/balance/0x1b0cab6db1672349b8f8a6d8d8903ab58ae0d734");
//Console.WriteLine(downloadString);
downloadString = downloadString.Replace('.', ',');
//Console.WriteLine(downloadString);
string[] first = downloadString.Split(':');
string ETH = first[2].Remove(first[2].Length-1);
Console.WriteLine(ETH);
string downloadString2 = client.DownloadString("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=CZK");
downloadString2 = downloadString2.Replace('.', ',');
string[] second = downloadString2.Split(':');
string CZK = second[1].Remove(second[1].Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(CZK);
float eth = float.Parse(ETH);
float czk = float.Parse(CZK);
Console.WriteLine("You have {0} CZK", eth * czk);
```

Is there a better way to remove every thing else from API then numbers?
Thanks

Comment: The response looks like a JSON formatted string.  You should be using a JSON parser to properly read the data. [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is one of the more popular ones.

Comment: Better, yes. Use HttpClient and Json.NET.

Comment: Time to learn sonething ab out [JSON](http://www.json.org)

Comment: I would also suggest you read about [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), and how it is connected with `WebClient` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you are getting back is JSON. Use a library to deserialize it.

[Newtonsoft's JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is popular

You can then do something like:

```
string responseString = client.DownloadString("https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/balance/0x1b0cab6db1672349b8f8a6d8d8903ab58ae0d734")
dynamic reponseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(repsonseString);
double data = responseObj.data;
```

Comment: Thanks, very simple :)

Answer (score 3):

It's return a JSON. You can parse it with a JSON parser.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Answer (score 0):

Lukas.

Why you don´t convert to an object?
   I think you can create a classes. 
   As here:

```
   public class Link1Data
   {
       public bool status { get; set; }
       public float data { get; set; }
   }


   public class Link2CZK
   {
       public float CZK { get; set; }
   }
```

Then change your code to:

```
   WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
   var data = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/balance/0x1b0cab6db1672349b8f8a6d8d8903ab58ae0d734");
   var ethData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Link1Data>(data);

   var data2 = webClient.DownloadString("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=CZK");
   var czkData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Link2CZK>(data2);

   Console.WriteLine("You have {0} CZK", ethData.data * czkData.CZK);
```

Based on:
   [How to convert a Stream into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106534/how-to-convert-a-stream-into-an-object#answer-28106601)

I did not test. ;-)